# AWS-CLI - Error with ec2-attributes

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

i'm trying to interact with an object in my S3 bucket from my EMR Cluster (i'm trying to ffmpeg a video located in s3://$mybucket/
I found that i have to add a role and create my cluster using these roles, my code is looks like that :

`EMR_CLUSTER_CREATION=$(aws emr create-cluster --name $cluster_name --release-label emr-5.4.0 --log-uri s3://$bucket_name/myLogs --applications Name=Hive Name=Pig \
    --service-role Proton-Test \
    --ec2-attributes KeyName=$ec2_key, InstanceProfile=Proton-Test --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge)
    echo "$EMR_CLUSTER_CREATION"`

But i get this error :

`Error parsing parameter '--ec2-attributes': Expected: '<second>', received: '<none>' for input:
KeyName=devenv-key,
                   ^`

Thanks in advance !

Alex

Comment: There should be no spaces I guess. `KeyName=$ec2_key,InstanceProfile=Proton-Test`

Comment: OmG.... Thanks dude <3

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the synthax, thanks to Sudharsan Sivasankaran !

`EMR_CLUSTER_CREATION=$(aws emr create-cluster --name $cluster_name --release-label emr-5.4.0 --log-uri s3://$bucket_name/myLogs --applications Name=Hive Name=Pig \
    --service-role Proton-Test \
    --ec2-attributes KeyName=$ec2_key,InstanceProfile=Proton-Test --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge)
    echo "$EMR_CLUSTER_CREATION"`

is now working, cluster created and working !